# SSAS Tabular Model - Query Mode with Partitions

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, analysisservices

I'm currently working on a tabular model project and I've been reading about the two modes for query mode: Direct Query and In-Memory.

In the 2012 version for VS there's an option to deploy the solution in Hybrid mode (compatibility 1100 I think), but since the 1103 version that's no longer available. I'm working right now with the latest version for SQL Server, (2019) and VS 2019. My team is currently working on having the solution deployed with the In-Memory option. We have almost 124GB of RAM and we've calculated that is enough for the DW.

My concern is about the RAM available in the future and if it is possible to have partitions working with both modes (like hybrid mode in 2012). For example, partitions for previous years working with InMemory and the current partition (2020 right now) with DirectQuery, is that possible?? That would mean that I would only have to refresh the older partitions once a year or once a month (depending on the requirements), or vice versa: the older partitions in DirectQuery and the current partition with InMemory.

Right now we don't need Real Time access for this solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I use Tabular with 1500 compatibility and I get an error when trying deploy model with mixed partition type. I get an error:

[image]

I thinking it is not possible to make what you wish.